# Not able to calibrate my touch screen for NItrogen 6 Max Board using ts_calibrate program

Tags: arm, cross-compiling

I cross compile the latest tslib source https://github.com/kergoth/tslib for my Nitrogen 6 Max arm Board.
When I execute the **ts_calibrate**  file its displayed the calibration message on screen with a cross pointer.

But when I touched on the screen it updates that tyouched area with actual desktop area.

But when I ran **ts_print** or **ts_print_raw** programs its displays the touch locations wherever i touched on the screen.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You touch the four/five areas when the `ts_calibrate` program runs.  This calibrates the touch co-ordinates to the screen co-ordinates.  It is not really clear what your problem is?  Have you set the environment variables to save the calibration data?  Does `ts_print` differ from `ts_print_raw`?  For capacitive touch, this calibration is likely not needed and you can hard code the translation as they are the same for all displays from the same factory.

Comment: Thanks..
When I touch the screen, my GUI will go off and the desktop screen will be visible.
So can't able to give touch coordinates to the ts_calibrate program.

Comment: You need to kill/suspend the other processes that are reading from the `/dev/input` touchscreen device while `ts_calibrate` runs.

Answer (score 0):

When you build a recent version of tslib from source, you can use `./configure --with-sdl2` which will give you a SDL2 version of `ts_calibrate` that you should be able to run in any other desktop environment "area".